# What is this 'RF 82' SMD component on a magnetic loop antenna board?

Tags: identification

I am trying to repair an AOR LA400 magnetic loop antenna board designed for amateur radio reception (AM to 30 MHz typical.) 5W was accidentally transmitted - the LA400 receive only.

They do not publish circuits and AOR unable to help or new board.

By comparing with a second working example I own, the Q8 component 'RF 82' behaves differently on pin checks. It is an SOT89 package but I can find no reference to this code online.

Any thoughts on the ID? I am tempted to try an RF amplifier in this position as a stab. It was right next to the coax in so the likely the first to go.

I found the SMD code bible linked to in the forum. There is only one 'RF' in SOT89 listed - an 2SC3357 NPN RF amplifier.  Is this the likely item although specs are for VHF and above not HF?

[image]

Comment: Hey David. Why the negative image? Why black and white?

Comment: Hi Davide, the letters are pale on a green background, the negative help them to be easier to read. rgds David

Comment: Q8 has now been replaced with a 2SC3357 transistor from a UK supplier. It was marked 'RF84'. The unit now performs correctly when compared with another example.
Fortunately the amateur HF transceiver was a low power QRP model with 5W maximum transmit, apparently limiting damage to the first active component at the radio interface. A typical amateur transceiver is often 100 to 200W and could, as the manual suggests, possibly irreparably damage the magnetic loop aerial as it is only designed for receive.

Comment: @david Please provide dimensions for the part.

Comment: It was the NEC 2SC3357 in the SOT-89 package, their part number NE85634. The datasheet is available online, size ca. 4.5 x 2.5 mm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Q designator means it's a transistor. And it is indeed easy enough to find on "S-Manuals" https://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/2/s/2sc3357_renesas.pdf and it does indeed appear to likely be the 2SC3357 LNA NPN transistor. Marking RF 82 where 82 is DC Current Gain.

Old NEC part, possibly still available from Renesas, but apparently sold by Rochester too, so maybe it's end of life.